# Using '. . .' for two purposes in a single R function

Tags: r, function

In my function below, I want to use `...` for two purposes. The first `...` is to be used so `...` could be turned to a `list(...)`. The second `...` is simply there to represent the graphical parameters (e.g., `col`, `font`, etc.).

I was wondering if there might be any way to use `...` OR any equivalent strategy so that my function works?

```
bb <- function(..., ...){

aa <- function(x, add){ if(!add) { plot(density(x), ...) } else { lines(density(x), ...) } 
} ## HERE `...` represents graphical parameters

z <- list(...) ## HERE `...` is used to form a list(...)
loop <- seq_len(length(z))

for(i in loop){ aa(z[[i]], add = i != 1, ... = ...) }
}

#When fixed, the function should work in the following example:

y1 <- rnorm(200)
y2 <- rnorm(200)

bb(y1, y2) # Should give two overlapping plots
```

Comment: Not really; how would you tell which parameters go to which ellipsis? You'd have to use a list for the purpose of one of them, and then use `do.call` (or something similar) to invoke the function that you want to pass those parameters to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be no way to separate the arguments given to a function into
two ellipses. To achieve the same functionality, you could replace one of
them with a `list` argument instead; in this case, the graphical parameters
might be a natural choice, but it depends on your intended use case.

To be able to call functions with the arguments specified in a list, you
can use `do.call`:

> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

```r
bb <- function(..., gpar = list()) {
  aa <- function(x, add) {
    # here we've replaced the direct calls to the plotting functions with
    # indirect calls with a given argument list
    if (!add) {
      do.call("plot", c(list(density(x)), gpar))
    } else {
      do.call("lines", c(list(density(x)), gpar))
    }
  }

  z <- list(...)
  loop <- seq_len(length(z))

  for (i in loop) {
    aa(z[[i]], add = i != 1)
  }
}
```

This modified version of the function should provide what you're after:

```r
set.seed(1)

y1 <- rnorm(200)
y2 <- rnorm(200)

bb(y1, y2, gpar = list(col = "red", lty = 2))
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use some heuristic to separate arguments given in
a single `...` to send them to the correct functions. In this case, one such
heuristic could be whether the arguments are named or not:

```r
bb2 <- function(...) {
  aa <- function(x, add, gpar) {
    # removed repetition by doing everything that
    # can be done outside of the conditional logic
    fun <- if (!add) "plot" else "lines"
    args <- c(list(density(x)), gpar)

    do.call(fun, args)
  }

  # capture all arguments
  dots <- list(...)

  # guarantee character vector of names
  nm <- names(dots)
  if (is.null(nm)) {
    nm <- rep("", length(dots))
  }

  # pick out named arguments
  gpar <- dots[nm != ""]

  # loop across unnamed args
  z <- dots[nm == ""]
  for (i in seq_along(z)) {
    aa(z[[i]], add = i != 1, gpar)
  }
}

bb2(y1, y2)
```

[image]

```r
bb2(y1, y2, col = "blue", lty = 3)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Well, if you don't need any named arguments other than those passed to the plotting functions, you could separate the arguments to `bb` based on whether or not they are named. The core of the problem is that you need to have some logic that will separate which arguments go where.

Comment: You *could*  do something like that with some clever use of `Map` for instance, but then you would be limited to scalar arguments to `plot`.